# There should be an easy way to look at your own answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page, network-profile

I answer a bunch of nginx-related questions on serverfault and stackoverflow, and I'd like to refer back to my original answers in some of the newer answers/comments, where the questions or subject matter are very similar.

The problem is -- people have really bad titles, plus there's this fragmentation between stackoverflow and serverfault on this nginx topic, amongst others.

There should be an easy way to see all your [recent] answers on a single page, in an expanded form.  I see it's already partially possible, through the *Activity* tab in the network profile, however, (1), although answers there are expandable, they are not expanded there by default, (2), there's no button to expand all answers at once, and, (3), there is no way to only look at the answers, you can only limit it to both the answers and the questions at the same time.

Changes I propose:

- the network profile, the `activity` tab:

  - be able to only look at the answers (`answered`), not just all `posts` (which also includes questions); basically, I'm asking for the `posts` subtab to be further separated into the `answered` and `asked`
  - have the ability to expand all items at once (the items are already expandable individually)
- the individual accounts on the network, the `answers` tab:

  - have the ability to expand the individual items
  - have the ability to expand all items at once

Comment: A workaround: on one network, you can use a search query to separate answers and sort them by activity. For example, here are your answers on [*Server Fault*](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a110020%20is%3aanswer) and [*Stack Overflow*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a1122270%20is%3aanswer), sorted by activity. You could bookmark the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. Go to your profile, look at the tags section, look for the tag your answer was in, and then click it. It will bring up posts by you only in that tag. Then you can append `is:answer` to the set. It should really narrow it down. If you need further searching, you can then add in some search terms.

Here is a link to your nginx answers [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1122270+%5Bnginx%5D+is%3Aanswer) and [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A110020+%5Bnginx%5D+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: The results are condensed, and I cannot see any of my solutions (i.e. the code), which is the whole point of why I want to look at the full answers.  It appears that the search only shows a couple of lines from each answer.  Besides, this means that I have to go back and forth between the two tabs in order to find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @cnst - It is not ideal. However, it is possible to make a custom website for answers such as was done at [Ask Jon Skeet](http://www.askjonskeet.com) (note: this site was not written by Jon Skeet).